# How are the two co-area formulas equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

In general, we have that for Lipschitz $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ the following co-area formula:
$$
\omega_n\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}g(x)\left\|\nabla f\right\|d\mathcal{H}^n(x)=\omega_1\omega_{n-1}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{f^{-1}(y)}g(z)d\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(z)d\mathcal{H}^1(y)
$$
But from multivariable calculus class, I learned that the co-area formula is presented as follows:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g(x)dx = \int_\mathbb{R} dy \int_{f^{-1}(y)} g(x) \frac{d\sigma}{|\nabla f|}.
$$
Here the $d\sigma$ is with respect to the surface $f^{-1}(y)$.

I thought that the two was equivalent by considering the function $G=h/|\nabla f|$, however the problem is that I don't see how to transform the $d\sigma$ in the second formula to make it into the same form as the first formula. Any explanation would be appreciated.